# Shopify Recurring Application Charge related issue

Tags: python, shopify

While testing Shopify recurring application charge today I got stuck in following issues, can anyone please look into this....

1. I created a test recurring charge, it worked fine but I was not able to locate where to accept the charge in my test Shopify shop using admin.
2. I can see or query the newly created test recurring-application-charge object but can not remove or cancel it. Whenever I tried to remove, it gave me a ResourceInvalid: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity

**I am using Shopify python api to interact with Shopify server.**

Answer (score 1):

> I created a test recurring charge, it worked fine but I was not able to locate where to accept the charge in my test Shopify shop using admin.

When you created your charge, you had to provide a callback so that Shopify could send the charge for you to accept. I would look there for it.

Comment: I provided the callback, but I believe callback would only occur if the shop owner accept the charge. As a developer / tester I logged into the shop-owner's account but could not see any pending charge. Where can I see it in test shop admin?

Comment: You believe incorrect. A callback is a callback. You check the charge itself to determine if it was accepted or denied. You do not get to see anything from the merchants perspective.